# Problemas con rutas static con node, express

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

Buenas Tarde, tengo un problema pero no doy con el chiste,
estoy vinculando un archivo llamado `appAllMarket.js` a mi `html` pero no encuentra la ruta, el problema que creo que pasa es que esta en una carpeta llamada **models** fuera de la carpeta **public**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El asunto es que no deseo que `appAllMarket.js` sea publico, por lo tanto no lo ubico en **public**

archivo jade:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
        meta(name="viewport",content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
        meta(name="description",content="")
        meta(name="author",content="")

        //link(rel="icon",href="../../favicon.ico")

        title AllMarket
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/estilos.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        //----------------------------------
        script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous")
        script(src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js")

        //------------------------------
        script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js")
        script(src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular-route.min.js")
        script(src='../models/appAllMarket.js')

    body
        block content
```

El error que lanza es:

> GET http://localhost:3000/models/appAllMarket.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: ¿Quieres usarlo como un javascript publico pero que a su vez no sea publico?

Comment: Si, es que dentro de los cursos que he visto hablan de las buenas practicas y dicen que maneje los modelos en una carpeta llamada models y en la raiz del proyecto, osea que no debe ir dentro de la carpeta public

Comment: ¿Que contiene el appAllMarket.js?

Comment: El modulo de angular, estoy implementando la tecnología de angular, esto ya lo había hecho en otro proyecto solo que no use node, y ahora estoy haciéndolo con node y esto convierte los demás directorios como privados y no puedo acceder a la ruta directamente como lo hacia en el anterior

Comment: Es que lo que quieres hacer es una incongruencia. Si **no** es público, no tiene URL pública, *ergo* no puedes acceder mediante una URL *normal*. Podrías hacerlo solicitandolo, por ejemplo, mediante AJAX y usando una cabecera especial, o mediante un POST debidamente *ofuscado* (para mantener la ocultación), o de cualquier otra forma que se te ocurra, **excepto**, precisamente, la que estas usando.